# Ag-Grid - Get cell list from RowNode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can i get the list of all cell instances in a specific row in Ag-Grid?

This is the gridOption object:

```
export const gridOptions = props => ({
    columnDefs: columnDefs(props),
    deltaRowDataMode: true,
    getRowNodeId: data => data.id,
    reactNext: true,
    loadingOverlayComponentFramework: Loader,
    onCellMouseOver: api => {
        // RowNode
        const row = api.node;
    },
});
```

In the `onCellMouseOver` method i have the RowNode class of the current hovered row. I tried to find some method in there as getCells but could not find anything...
Is there any other way?

Comment: what do you mean you want to "list of all cell instances"? get the cell data?

Comment: @ViqMontana not just the data rendered in the cell, but something similar to the RowNode class for the cell, for example CellNode, that would contain the cell properties and APIs

Comment: the concept of a CellNode doesn't exist in ag-Grid. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ViqMontana I am adding a column at the end of the grid with hidden content and width:0.
On hover i want to select the cell of the hovered row in that last column and give width 100% to fill all the row and give an effect as an overlay with some button inside

Comment: @ViqMontana actually exists a getCellRendererInstances, but it return just the customised cell...i expected a method that returns all the cells contained in a row

Comment: sorry, your question is very unclear. Please update your question and specify exactly what you're trying to achieve.